# Cant access wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin

After changing the site URL in settings I am no longer able to access the wp-admin page.
When I enter the new URL it says:

> Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.

I am no sure what to do now.

Edit: Tried to add the following lines to wp-config.php file but it didn’t help

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com');
```

Comment: Anything that I can try? I can’t access the website anymore

Comment: What did you change the URL to? Do you own that domain? Is it pointed to your server?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the server